# Is this the right way to add an iterator to a class?

Tags: python

I have some code that expects classes to provide an iterator. In other words, the code
several time looks like

```
A=aClass()
for f in A:
   doSomething(f)
```

Here `doSomething()` expects `f` to be an instance of a specific class `F`. In general, `aClass()` contains a member `_myfList=tuple(f1,f2,...)` where `f1` `f2` etc. are instances of `F` and returns an interator that iterates over `_myfList`. If I want to run the case where `aClass=F`, is it enough to modify `F` as follows?

```
class F():
   def __init__(self):
      # existing code
      ...
      # new code
   
      self._it=(self,) 

   def __iter__(self): # this is the iterator
      return iter(self._it)
```

simple tests seem to show that it works, but
my concern is that defining `self._it=(self,)` smacks of an endless loop, and indeed I cannot understand why it works.

Comment: What tests did you run? Your iterator is iterating over a single element and nothing more. Any test that does more than "Does this function terminate? Great!" should've detected a big problem, unless that's actually for some reason what you wanted to happen.

Answer (score 0):

> my concern is that defining self._it=(self,) smacks of an endless loop, and indeed I cannot understand why it works.

Since your for loop is iterating over a 1-element tuple based on your definition of the `F` class, I'm unclear as to why you might think it would be endless. Your `iter(self._it)` returns an iterator created from a 1-element tuple.